# Any idea for an Algorithm to distribute work between users, ensuring that all have at least "nice work"?

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks, pseudocode

I have been struggling for the past months for an algorithm of something I usually do by hand. I'm pretty sure there must be some ideas there, but I haven't found any.

The problem is the following:

Lets say we have X users and X work to do (the same amount of users and work). Some of this work is nasty, boring, or just exhausting, while other is nice, creative and open. I'd like to be able to generate a work-list to give to each user for a week, having a different position every day (for example). Of course, all the users deserve to have "nice times" and the "boring tasks" have to be done too...

In a really small example:

> Tasks = X (boring) / Y (cool)
>
> Users = A / B
>
> Day 1:
>
> > A -> X
> > B -> Y
>
> Day 2:
>
> > A -> Y
> > B -> X

The main idea is to have an even workflow between all the users (so all have bad and good works).

Extra points if it is possible to define that some users are  more "special" and deserve "better treats". Also, the tasks may be categorized not just as "good/bad" but with a numbered scale.

---

What I have thought so far:

The best algorithm or idea I came with is to sort the users and give the prefered ones first the best places, until I distribute all the work. Then for the second day I swap the worst with the best and so on (1 with X, 2 with X-1...). Here my concerns:

- Dont know how to continue for the third day (If I repeat the same idea, 1 will be back to 1, X to X and then they will only do two tasks in their whole week...
- The preferred one, number one, gets to do the "worst task" X. Also, the ones in the middle may not change of task (just bad & bad).

Please let me know if I can explain my idea better or if you have any hints in mind. (Graphs, other possible ideas, etc, included).

Comment: When you have an answer don't forget to organize a political party around it :)

Comment: @biziclop Haha. I usually do these things (by hand) for volunteers work in some events. There are cool tasks and non-cool ones. :)

Comment: Where is this work at, I want to give it a wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide berth.

Comment: Well, count the ratio of Good to bad. For every B bad tasks, there'll be G good tasks per user. Still, using incentives and reward systems generally works extremely well. So well in fact that people have avoided filling prescriptions for life saving drugs just to get air miles. So spread the labour and give tough tasks to people with enough motivation to push through, and the easy tasks to those who don't have much motivation.

Comment: It feels like related to k-partition problem with an extra constraint on choice of elements, where #users=k, and "value" is the numbers in the set, and you want to distribute the "values" as evenly as possible. No idea though if this constraint makes this problem in P or not.

Comment: Refreshing memories about image dithering may be inspirative :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither Also every worker should make a preference list of their favourite/hated work types, and a reverse list too: who does a given work the best.

Comment: @Aarowaim Well, they all work perfectly motivated. And its not fair to the well motivated ones to keep them in the same line for all the week... :)

Comment: @amit Could you give me more details? I think you might be in a good track.

Comment: @charlypu I am not sure this is indeed NP-Complete (my gut is sure it is...), but if my suspecion is correct and the problem is similar to [k-partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_k-partition_problem), this is strong np-complete problem which doesn't even have pseudo-polynomial solution (unless P=NP). I am trying to think of a reduction, but cannot find it yet.

Comment: @amit I was thinking that was NP for sure since day 1. Nevertheless at least a starting point is better than keep doing it by pen and paper for dozens of workers :). I would love the "best response" but an algorithm for the "best approximation" is also really welcomed!

Comment: Make a schedule for everyone, an entire week in advance (or whatever longer time period fits). If all jobs take (about) the same time, define a metric for "boring" and sort on that. Then fill each person's schedule, starting with the most popular person/job. I think it boils down to a minimized-sum-of-squares algorithm that way.

Comment: @charlypu Yeah. If a person gets work they don't have adequate skill for, they will get frustrated. Some will be much more skilled and/or efficient and blaze through tasks while others need a lot of time. Get the task done & well, and each person should have one task to avoid idleness. The task is likely too difficult if the person takes too long. Their next task should be simpler to avoid overwork & frustration. Complex tasks may need to be redistributed, so I don't recommend assigning more than one at a time per person.

Comment: @charlypu One thing I learnt moving furniture; one person may carry a heavy object, or an awkwardly shaped object, but it takes two to carry something heavy & awkward. In a sense, the same applies here; complex (heavy) & awkward (boring) together make a task much more difficult than alone.

Comment: Run an auction every week and let people maximize their own priorities.

Answer (score 0):

I belive in addition to assign a status of boring and cool, you could find out the (average) amount of time that every activity takes so that way you could make a balance of work. That's how asembly lines are balance (based on the amount of time), all cells of work must have sort of same amount of time of work assigged every day, so that way some cells of work will have for example 12 to 20 activities while some just one or two, but the amout of time will be aproximatly the same.

Comment: Good idea, although the work takes the same time being cool or boring. Exactly the same time... :(

Comment: Then maybe a weight assigned to each activity (for example 1-10) boring activities could be 6-10 and cool 1-5, and from here you could make a balance. (Just would be necesary a little research to find the weight you will assigned to each activity).